# Invariance of oriented intersections on surface with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Suppose that we have two smooth, simple closed curves $\alpha, \beta : S^{1} \rightarrow \Sigma$ in a closed, connected, oriented surface $\Sigma$, and suppose that $\alpha \cap \beta$ consists of finitely many points, all of which are transverse intersections. Then we can define the oriented intersection number $i(\alpha,\beta)$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as the sum of oriented intersection numbers $i_{p}(\alpha,\beta)$ at the intersection points $p$, where $i_{p}(\alpha,\beta)$ is $\pm 1$ depending on whether the crossing $\alpha,\beta$ is positive or negative with respect to the orientation on $\Sigma$.

The oriented intersection number $i(\alpha,\beta)$ can be computed algebraically in terms of Poincar'e duality. Namely, let $[\alpha],[\beta] \in H_{1}(\Sigma)$ be the homology classes, $[\alpha]^{\vee},[\beta]^{\vee} \in H^{1}(\Sigma)$ the Poincar'e dual cohomology classes (duality being with respect to the fixed orientation). Then $$i(\alpha,\beta)=[\alpha]^{\vee} \cup [\beta]^{\vee} \in H^{2}(\Sigma) \simeq H_{0}(\Sigma) \simeq Z.$$
(Here we have used duality again.)

I'd like to generalize this kind of calculation to intersections of smooth but not necessarily closed curves in a connected, oriented surface $(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma)$ with boundary, where the end points of non-closed curves are required to lie in the boundary $\partial \Sigma$ and the curves don't intersect on the boundary. The sum $i(\alpha,\beta)$ over signed intersection numbers still makes sense, but it's unclear to me what invariance properties it has, and whether it can be computed algebraically in terms of Leftschetz duality.

Questions:

1. In the situation above with boundary, is it true that $i(\alpha,\beta)$ is invariant under homotopy/isotopy relative to the boundary (that is, fixing the boundary pointwise)?
2. Can $i(\alpha,\beta)$ be computed "algebraically", maybe using Lefschetz duality?
3. If the above are true, are there textbook or research paper references?

Concerning 2), what I tried and what didn't work is the following:

Suppose $\alpha, \beta$ are non-closed curves with end points in the boundary $\partial \Sigma$. Then they define relative homology classes in $H_{1}(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma) \simeq H^{1}(\Sigma)$, where the last isomorphism is Lefschetz duality. But now if you try to cup together the dual classes, you get a class in $H^{2}(\Sigma)$, which is zero because $\Sigma$ is not closed. So this is useless.

Answer (score 1):

The algebraic intersection pairing on a compact oriented surface $\Sigma$ with boundary is a pairing
$$\omega\colon H_1(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma) \times H_1(\Sigma) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}.$$
Note here that one input lies in relative homology (so can take in arcs whose endpoints lie on the boundary) and the other input is in ordinary homology (so can just take in loops).  There does not exist a well-defined pairing between $H_1(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma)$ and itself; indeed, in $H_1(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma)$ you can move endpoints of arcs freely around in a boundary component, creating new intersections if you try to pair arcs with arcs.

You can see that this works out nicely with Poincare duality.  Indeed, it is dual to the pairing
$$H^1(\Sigma) \times H^1(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$
coming from the cup product map
$$H^1(\Sigma) \times H^1(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma) \rightarrow H^2(\Sigma,\partial \Sigma) = \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Note that you are answering a different question from the one in the OP.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Yes, I suppose that's true.  While the answer to the OP's first question is "yes" (just think about how the intersection number changes under Reidemeister-type moves), it doesn't lead to a good homological intersection theory.  What I described in my answer is what is in my experience the most useful thing to think about in this setting.